# Subgroups of external direct product.

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find all subgroups of order 4 in Z<sub>4</sub> x Z<sub>4</sub>.
I have:

- $\{0\} \times Z_4 = \langle(0,1)\rangle$
- $Z_4 \times \{0\} = \langle(1,0)\rangle$
- $\langle(1,1)\rangle$
- $\langle(0,2)\rangle$

Have I missed any?

Comment: What about $\;\langle (1,0)\rangle\;,\;\;\langle (0,1)\rangle$ ? BTW, $\;2\cdot (0,2)=(0,0)\implies \langle (0,2)\rangle\;$ has order two.

Comment: isn't that first one of order 8?

Comment: It can't be @Paul as the group's exponent is $\;4\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio what do you mean by $\;\langle (1,0)\rangle\;,\;\;\langle (0,1)\rangle$?  If you mean $\langle (1,0)\rangle$ and $\langle (0,1)\rangle$, both of those are listed.

Comment: Either I missed those (as usual), or were edited before 5 minutes passed, @Omnomnomnom...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\langle (0,2) \rangle$ is not of order $4$.  However, $\langle (0,2),(2,0) \rangle$ is.

Note additionally that you're missing $\langle(1,3)\rangle,\langle(1,2)\rangle$, and $\langle(2,1)\rangle$.